# TypeError: stylis middleware is not a function

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

Trying to run a test, but an error was thrown (TypeError: stylis.middleware is not a function), anyone has faced same issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Since there aren't any answers online my fix was removing both `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` from the `package.json`.

**However**
It's probably better to try and find a solid fix if you need to use `@emotion` which could be trying newer releases, or following the upgrade docs for `@mui` in full https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/

In my case this was triggered only on some pages and only in our development environment. I believe it was caused by having incorrect `@emotion` package dependencies which use `stylis` internally inside out web bundle. These were only added as peer dependencies for `@mui` v5 (which we had since removed) and although no `@mui` or `@emotion` libraries were being imported directly, this error was still thrown on certain pages.